# Where is Clone implemented for [u32; N]?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that I want to implement `.clone_from()` for to reuse a stack allocation. The struct is relatively simple (all types in it are `Copy` except a `[u32; N]`). I could blindly just call `a.clone_from(&b)` on the `a : [u32; N]`, but it is possible that the `.clone_from()` implementation for this type in the standard library is not good, and that this will compute `let a = b.clone()`, and will not reuse the stack allocation.

So, I want to look at the Clone implementation of arrays myself to make sure, but I am having difficulty finding it within the nightly docs. I have looked in:

1. The [clone doc page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) and [clone source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/clone.rs.html#107-131). I see nothing like `impl <const N : usize> Clone for [T; N]` in either of these places
2. The [array (primitive type)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) and [array source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#406-509), where again I see no implementation.

So where is the implementation? How can I check that calling `a.clone_from(&b)` will reuse my allocation?

Comment: `[u32; N]` is `Copy` as well, see the [array (primitive type)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) documentation that you already linked.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed-size arrays of types that implement `Copy` (like `u32`) automatically implement `Copy` so they are efficiently copied bit-wise, see the [array (primitive type) documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html).